# intersection of any collection of rings (or semirings) of subsets of X is again a ring (or semiring) of subsets of X

Tags: measure-theory

I have to prove that the intersection of any collection of rings (or semirings) of subsets of X is again a ring (or semiring) of subsets of X.
If we look at the ring case. I know that to prove a ring we have to show three thing 
1) it contains the empty set 
2) it contains the union 
3)it contains the difference of sets.
1)We are looking at the intersection of a collection of rings. Every set in every collection is a ring and so every collection contains the empty set and so the intersection contains the empty set.
2) For property 2 we have to show that If A is the intersection of a collection of rings and B is the intersection of another collection of rings then $A\cup B$ is also an intersection of a collection of rings? Is this correct? And if so how have I to prove it?
3)For property 3 we have to show that If A is the intersection of a collection of rings and B is also an intersection of another collection of rings then $A\backslash B$ is the intersection of a collection of rings? Is this correct? And if so how have I to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is in the intersection of the rings of our collection and $B$ is in the intersection of the rings in our collection, than each ring in the collection contains both $A$ and $B$, hence (them being rings) each contains $A\cup B$, hence the intersection contains $A\cup B$. Obviously, the same argument works for any finite-ary operation, in particular also for $(A,B)\mapsto A\setminus B$. (Note that the claim about $\emptyset$ is also of this type with a $0$-ary operation)